# Query Rules in sharepoint 2013 for searching mobile phones

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results, query-rule

Im set search to show numbers of mobile phones my users, but I cant found users if try to search with their number.
In profile: "+0 (111) 222-33-44"
In search Im try: "+01112223344", "1112223344" and nothing...
Im gets results if try:"222-33-44", "111" or full number.

Need to found "+0 (111) 222-33-44" from "+01112223344", "1112223344" and etc.

In query rules im found this reg-ex for "Phone Number in people search": "((^(?!(([\d-.\s()+]*([a-df-su-wyzA-DF-SU-WYZ]+|[tT]|[eE](?|[xX][a-zA-Z]+)[eExXtT]+.?\s?(?\d+)?$)|(^(?=(+|00|0)(\d{4,-})$)(")?(+|00|0)(?\d+)(")?$)"

and in search constructor has: "PhoneNumber:"{area?}{number1?}{number2?}{extension?}""

In search schema PhoneNumber dont gets any information...

But work phone in format (000) 11-22, i can found with: "1122"

Pls help to understand this rule with parameters and create new rule for mobile phones (regex for this type number - example: "^((8|+7)[- ]?)?((?\d{3})?[- ]?)?[\d- ]{7,10}$")

Answer (score 0):

did you ever figure this out?
I have a similar situation, and need to understand where the values in PhoneNumber comes from and the magic behind it.